# Synchronization between two processes in C#.?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

Is there any way so that we can synchronize two independent processes? Like if they are sharing a resource, I would like to sync them.

I am using C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the Mutex class

see documentation here :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Comment: More specifically, you need to use a named mutex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WCF with pipe binding, or named synchronization objects, Mutex for example for synchronization between two processes

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes will give you cross process sync.

You could also implement an API in WCF using named pipes, which could give you a nice synchronisation in OO code without system calls and it fully unit testable.  Named pipes would also give you not just sync but communication as well.